# convert a formatted color cell to a percentage in a different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have conditional formatting in a cell that ranges from 1-5.
1= green
2= green
3= green
4= yellow
5= red

I am trying to change the 1-5 in a different cell to reflect a certain percentage.
1= green and should be 95%
2= green and should be 90%
3= green and should be 85%
4= yellow and should be 80%
5= red and should be 75%

Answer (score 0):

*One helper column solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Helper Column is `D`, so the formula in `D1`:

  ```
  =IF(AND($A1=1,$B1=95%),1,IF(AND($A1=2,$B1=90%),2,IF(AND($A1=3,$B1=85%),3,IF(AND($A1=4,$B1=80%),4,IF(AND($A1=5,$B1=75%),5,0)))))
  ```
- Reach to **C**onditional format then **N**ew Rule.
- For

**G**reen   `=OR($D1=1,$D1=2,$D1=3)`

**Y**ellow  `=$D1=4`

**R**ed     `=$D1=5`

**N.B :**

*For clear visibility I've used different color than RED for `5 & 75%`, you may alter it.*

---

- Later on for neatness you may hide the Helper Column then your data look like shown below.

[image]

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*